# Issue loading json data through AngularJs

Tags: json, angularjs

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
{{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country + ', ' + x.City  }}
</li>
</ul>
<p ng-repeat="y in localnames">{{ y.Adrs + ', ' + y.Place + ', ' + y.Country  }}</p>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("customers.json")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
  .success(function (response) {$scope.localnames =   response.locrecords;});
});

//JSON
{
"records":[
{"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"},
{"Name":"Comércio Mineiro","City":"São Paulo","Country":"Brazil"}
]

"locrecords":[
    {"Adrs":"My Address","Place":"Mavelikara","Country":"India"},
    {"Adrs":"My Address","Place":"Mavelikara","Country":"India"}
]
}
```

I am trying to load JSON data to HTML with Angular.js. Why is it not working after adding the second array? It does work when removing `$scope.localnames` .

The data and HTML used are here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4DOAWmRNQn1cGNEWVRqOU9xUVE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You got syntax error in you javascript code. you should remove the extra `;`:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("customers.json")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;})
  .success(function (response) {$scope.localnames =   response.locrecords;});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking your `$http` chaining.

```
$http.get("customers.json")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;}); <-- remove ;
  .success(function (response) {$scope.localnames = response.locrecords;});
```

Also, your JSON is broken. You are missing `,` (comma) after `records` array.

**JSON**

```
{
"records":[
{"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"},
{"Name":"Comércio Mineiro","City":"São Paulo","Country":"Brazil"}
],

"locrecords":[
    {"Adrs":"My Address","Place":"Mavelikara","Country":"India"},
    {"Adrs":"My Address","Place":"Mavelikara","Country":"India"}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question. You're JSON is NOT valid. You missed a `,` between records and locrecords. Formatting the code helps ;-)

```
{
 "records": [{
   "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
   "City": "Berlin",
   "Country": "Germany"
 }, {
   "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
   "City": "São Paulo",
   "Country": "Brazil"
 }],

 "locrecords": [{
   "Adrs": "My Address",
   "Place": "Mavelikara",
   "Country": "India"
 }, {
   "Adrs": "My Address",
   "Place": "Mavelikara",
   "Country": "India"
 }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix both JSON and HTML

HTML

```
$http.get("customers.json")
 .success(function (response) {
   $scope.names = response.records;
   $scope.localnames = response.locrecords;
});
```

JSON

```
{
 "records":[
  {"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"},
  {"Name":"Comércio Mineiro","City":"São Paulo","Country":"Brazil"}
 ],
 "locrecords":[
  {"Adrs":"My Address","Place":"Mavelikara","Country":"India"},
  {"Adrs":"My Address","Place":"Mavelikara","Country":"India"}
 ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Its array,
I think u have to call like below,
$scope.localnames =   response.locrecords[0]

And if its not working then u should call parseJSON(data[0]) on it.

Thanks,
Samrat Sarkar
blog: coderstutorial.blogspot.com

Comment: OP wants whole array, not first item from it. Also using `$http` gives proper object, no parsing required.

Comment: Sorry, still no. See my answer.

Comment: Yes i agree with u, u want to mean json and extra success its not proper